# atom git login window not showing login box

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

In atom, when I have already done a commit and I want to push to github through atom, it does not show the user-name and password box that it's suppose to show, it instead shows this: [image: How it looks]

it's quite annoying, can I make so that I don't need to open a terminal and make it so that is just to press push and enter my username and password?

Comment: What does `git config --list --show-origin` say?

Comment: @Christoph error: unknown option `show-origin'

Comment: What is your git version?

Comment: @Christoph git version 2.7.4

Comment: I can't figure out anymore when they introduced this feature. Perhaps you should just update git. My version is 2.16.2.windows. Just download and install.